# Mathematical Induction and subsets

Tags: group-theory, induction

Mathematical Induction is a technique used to prove statements that apply to a set S, where S is a subset of the nonnegative integers. To what types of sets would one apply generalized induction?

Comment: If you search Google for "generalized induction" and look at any of the definitions that come up, what do they say about the set in question?

Comment: I imagine it would come up a bit in basic number theory results. Probably not as much in abstract algebra where there aren't going to be a lot of orderings (linear or otherwise).

Comment: so generalized induction is used to prove sets other than integers that have the well ordering property?